# How to estimate $\sum_{|\alpha|\leq p} \binom{p}{|\alpha|}$?

Tags: inequality

I'm trying to find some estimates for some PDE I'm working on. I'd like to estimate the sum $$\sum_{|\alpha|\leq p} \binom{p}{|\alpha|},$$ where $\alpha\in\mathbb N_0^n$ and $\mathbb N_0=\mathbb N\cup\{0\}$. I know, $$\#\{\alpha\in\mathbb N_0^n: |\alpha|\leq p\}=\binom{p+n}{p},$$ hence the following inequality holds, $$\sum_{|\alpha|\leq p} \binom{p}{|\alpha|}\leq \binom{p+n}{p}\max_{|\alpha|\leq p}\binom{p+n}{p}.$$ But I'm wondering if there is a more elegant estimate for the above sum. Can anyone help me?

Comment: What is $\#\{\alpha \in \mathbb N^n_0:\ |\alpha|=p\}$? Maybe you could transform the sum then?

Comment: The $\alpha$s for which $|\alpha|=k$ are precisely the weak $n$-part integer compositions of $k$. There is an explicit formula for counting these [explained on Wikipedia here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_(combinatorics)#Number_of_compositions). Hence the sum is $$(\circ)=\sum_{k=0}^p\binom{p}{k}\binom{k+n-1}{n-1}.$$ WolframAlpha says this equals the hypergeometric function ${}_2F_1(n,-p;1;-1)$.

Comment: $\#$ means the cardinality..